# Linearity of the map Field Trace.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

![I want to prove that this map is well-defined. I know that the image of 'a' is sum of all Galois conjugates of 'a' i.e. the roots of minimal polynomial 'a' over Fq. I can prove the linearty of this map but my question is how this sum is an element of Fq.
Please help me I have stucked here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByQzV.jpg)

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to MSE.  You will have more luck getting quality answers if your entire question appears here, rather than a link to a picture of your question.  (For one thing, your question cannot be found by search if it is only present as a picture.)  Also, use of [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will improve the readability of your question.

Comment: The sum of Galois conjugates is invariant under the action of the Galois group. Those invariant elements are exactly the elements of the base field. Done.

Comment: The other [dupe target](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1791639/11619) suggested by Dietrich would serve well also. I spent a while looking for a dupe specific to finite fields (where the concrete description of the Galois group nominally simplifies things). Not much difference between the two. Dietrich's is more general.